# Is it possible to index and slice ReadOnlySpan<char> using Unicode text elements?

Tags: c#, unicode, .net-core

One way to handle the complexities of Unicode with strings is to use the text element functionality provided by `System.Globalization.StringInfo`. My question is whether there is a good way of indexing/slicing `ReadOnlySpan<char>` in terms of text elements to avoid allocations in parsing code that handles text elements (parsing is described in [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) as one of the areas that could benefit from reducing allocations by using `ReadOnlySpan<char>`), or would this require a large amount of reimplementation of the Unicode algorithms in my code?

Comment: `StringInfo` is actually not a very exciting class; it's a fairly thin wrapper around the functionality of `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory`. Unfortunately that, too, only offers an interface taking either a solitary `char` or a `string` with an index, not a `ReadOnlySpan`. The clean solution would be to petition the [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) people to implement the necessary overrides, or better yet, submit a pull request to that effect (it's not particularly hard; `CharUnicodeInfo.InternalGetCategoryValue` is the real work horse, and that uses UTF-32 stored in an `int`).

Comment: `StringInfo.GetCurrentTextElementLen` is the non-boring part of `StringInfo`, which likewise operates on `string` when it could easily operate on a `Span`.